# Git push on new local branch updates master instead of creating new remote branch

Tags: git, github, git-push

Problem: 
When my co-worker tries to push a new local branch to the repository, a new remote branch is not created. Instead, the commit from the local branch is pushed directly to the master branch.

Example Code:

```
$ git checkout -b newBranch origin/master
<make change to file>
$ git commit -am"newBranch commit message"
$ git push origin newBranch
```

Instead of getting the expected message ending with

```
* [new branch]      newBranch -> newBranch
```

my co-worker gets a message ending with this

```
deee5b8..756bf15  newBranch -> master
```

I tested this exact process on my machine and it worked just as expected; a new remote branch was created in the repository after the push.

This behavior is repeatable across multiple repositories and happens every time he tries to push a new branch to the repo. If the branch already exists on the repo, the commit is pushed to the branch as expected.

I'm assuming the difference is a setting or config option on my co-worker's machine, but I have been unable to identify the culprit. Hoping someone else has run into this before. Just let me know if I left out any key information. Thanks.

Comment: In relation to torek's answer: which version of Git is your coworker using? Push defaults have changed a bit in a recent version...

Comment: @Jubobs my co-worker is on git 1.9 and I am on 1.8. torek's solution seems to have fixed the problem, though my current push.default value is upstream and I am not experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt he has `push.default` set to `upstream` (as a `--global` configuration item; technically it could also be `--system` but that's much less likely).  He might want to use `simple` instead.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_variables) (under "variables", very long list).